# Send map with specific key via html form

Tags: forms, go

I have a form look like this

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="metadata[mimetype]" value="text/plain"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="metadata[size]" value="1024" />
    <input type="hidden" name="metadata[type]"  value="file" />
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

In my Go app I want to get a map look like this

```
["mimetype":"text/plain",...]
```

but I am getting  `metadata["mimetype"]` as key

Here is a my logic in Go

```
for key, values := range rq.Form {
            if len(values) > 0 {
                value := values[0]
                fmt.Println(key, value)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply change the form input names to remove the `metadata[]` part?

If this can't be done for some reason (e.g. client side Javascript relies on these names) then you could create a new map with something like the below:

```
values := make(map[string]string)
for k, v := range r.Form {
    if len(v) > 0 {
        k = strings.TrimPrefix(k, "metadata[")
        k = strings.TrimSuffix(k, "]")
        values[k] = v[0]
    }
}
```

*Note this is assuming there is only one input with each name (`string` as opposed to `[]string`) as this is the format you indicated your map should be in.*